# Multi user web software update solution

Tags: updates, symbolic-link

I want to accomplish an easy update procedure for web software that is used by multiple users.

The idea is to have the software with multiple versions at `/opt/software/version-1.2.3/` or `/opt/software/version-1.2.4/`.

In the `public-html/` folders of the users there are symlinks to the latest version of the software, that can easily be changed if there is a new version of the software.

This does not work though, if there are user-specific config files or subfolders like for example data/, that may not be updated and need to be taken to the next version.

What are best practice ideas on how I can accomplish this for future easy updates?